# работа с потоками c++

Tags: c++, многопоточность, mutex

Я сделал синхронизацию работы двух потоков, создаваемых классом example каким-то супер костыльным методом (используя проверку с id), как мне правильно реализовать завершение работы 1 потока после запуска 2?

То есть, создаю объект класса example в main'е -> из конструктора запускается 1 поток, который с интервалом в 2 секунды выводит сообщение с id потока в консоль. main поток усыпляю на 10 секунд, после чего запускаю 2 поток. Т.к. 2 поток запущен, мне нужно чтобы 1 поток, проснувшись, сразу же завершил свою работу, не выполняя никаких действий внутри цикла. Наверное, теоретически правильным будет сделать это с помощью mutex, но я пока не понял как.

Результат, если не добавлять проверку с id (работает сразу 2 потока):

```
16596
16596
16596
16596
16596
9104
16596
9104
16596
9104
16596
9104
16596
9104
16596
9104
```

Результат (тот, что мне как раз нужен, созданный 2 поток уже не работает параллельно с 1, т.к. первый завершил свою работу, остановив цикл) с проверкой id:

```
18356
18356
18356
18356
18356
15788
15788
15788
15788
15788
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>

class example
{
    std::atomic_bool m_do_loop_iteration;
    std::thread m_thread;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::atomic_int m_id;

    void start()
    {
        m_id++;

        m_thread = std::thread([&]()
        {
            //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
            int id = m_id.load();

            while (do_loop_iteration())
            {
                if (id != m_id.load())
                {
                    break;
                }

                std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
            }
        });
    }

public:
    example() :
        m_do_loop_iteration(true),
        m_id(0)
    {
        start();
    }

    bool do_loop_iteration()
    {
        return m_do_loop_iteration.load();
    }

    void restart()
    {
        m_thread.detach();
        start();
    }
};

int main()
{
    example ex;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    ex.restart();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(9999999));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вместо `detach()` следует выполнять `join()`. А раз вы получаете нужный результат, то в чем прблема?

Comment: мой способ выглядит каким-то костылем, возможно есть более рациональный вариант реализации, например, с использованием mutex

Comment: Вообще-то у тебя тут три потока, а не два. Третий поток - main. Убери лишний поток и будет понятнее. Как раз `join()` тебе тут пригодится, чтобы в main потоке дождаться завершения другого потока.

Comment: я понимаю, что у меня 3 потока, но join() мне не нужен, т.к в моей программе мне не надо останавливать работу вызывающего потока

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mutex сам по себе позволяет только блокировать одновременный доступ нескольких потоков к участку кода. А вот condition_variable больше подходит для такого случая, так как позволяет ожидать чего-либо не нагораживая костылей из sleep или busy loop.

[online compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/rk6arERdL)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>

class example
{
    ::std::thread m_thread;
    ::std::mutex m_mutex;
    ::std::condition_variable m_cond;
    bool m_loop;
    int m_counter;

    private: void start(void)
    {
        m_loop = true;
        m_thread = ::std::thread{&example::thread_routine, this};
    }

    private: void thread_routine(void)
    {
        ::std::unique_lock lock{m_mutex};
        do
        {
            ::std::cout << m_counter << ::std::endl;
        }
        while
        (
            not m_cond.wait_for
            (
                lock
            ,   ::std::chrono::seconds{1}
            ,   [this](void)
                {
                    return not m_loop;
                }
            )
        );
    }

    private: void stop(void)
    {
        {
            ::std::lock_guard lock{m_mutex};
            m_loop = false;
        }
        m_cond.notify_one();
        m_thread.join();
        ++m_counter;
    }

    public: example(void): m_loop{}, m_counter{}
    {
        start();
    }

    public: ~example(void)
    {
        stop();
    }

    public: void restart(void)
    {
        stop();
        start();
    }
};

int main()
{
    example ex{};
    for (;;)
    {
        ::std::this_thread::sleep_for(::std::chrono::seconds{3});
        ex.restart();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, прочитал немного про условные переменные, они же используются для синхронизации работы потоков. Но мне при наличии 2 работающего потока, 1 становится совсем ненужным. И получается, что особого смысла в том, чтобы мне следить за 1 потоком, нет (ложные срабатывания например). Почему-то сразу не подумал про флаг joinable(), перед запуском 2 потока, 1 я всегда отсоединяю(detach()). Можно в рабочем цикле проверять наличие флага joinable и в случае его отсутствия завершать цикл и поток соответственно. Но возможно я в чем-то ошибаюсь

Comment: @daniel Для синхронизации используются мьютексы. А кондвары - для контролируемого ожидания. Следить за первым потоком необходимо в любом случае. А вызов detach практически всегда является грубой ошибкой, ведь по сути это утрата контроля над состоянием потока.

Comment: А что плохого может произойти в моем случае? В main я создаю объект gateway класса, который служит для "общения" с сервером по websocket протоколу, мембером gateway является std::thread, который постоянно в фоновом режиме пингует сервер (поток проснулся, пинганул сервер, заснул, т. е. он работает в цикле,  while (m_connected)), при подключении к серверу я создаю поток, при отключении отсоединяю и меняю статус мембера bool gateway::m_connected на false и вызываю detach() для объекта, к которому прицеплен поток, соответственно, когда он в следующий раз проснётся, то его работа завершится.

Comment: Наверное, мне просто стоит в деструкторе gateway вызвать join().

Comment: В общем разобрался с условными переменными, это действительно то, что мне было нужно, благодарю.
Код, который написал себе для примера прикреплю, как ответ на собственный вопрос, мб кому-то поможет когда-нибудь

Comment: @daniel По поводу использования detach можете почитать [мой ответ на анг. со](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803600/when-should-i-use-stdthreaddetach/58222149#58222149)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>

class Gateway
{
    std::thread m_thread;
    std::condition_variable m_cond_var;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::atomic_bool m_connected;

    void connect();

public:
    void on_close(bool reconnect = false);
    bool is_connected() const;

    Gateway();
    ~Gateway();
};

void Gateway::connect()
{
    std::cout << "Gateway::connect - start" << std::endl;

    m_connected = true;

    m_thread = std::thread([&]()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

        while (is_connected())
        {
            std::cout << "ping " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
            m_cond_var.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(2), [&]() { return not is_connected(); });
        }
    });

    std::cout << "Gateway::connect - end" << std::endl;
}

void Gateway::on_close(bool reconnect)
{
    std::cout << "Gateway::on_close - start" << std::endl;

    if (is_connected())
    {
        m_connected = false;
        m_cond_var.notify_one();
        m_thread.join();
    }

    if (reconnect)
        connect();

    std::cout << "Gateway::on_close - end" << std::endl;
}

bool Gateway::is_connected() const
{
    return m_connected.load();
}

Gateway::Gateway() :
    m_connected(false)
{
    connect();
}

Gateway::~Gateway()
{
    m_connected = false;
    m_cond_var.notify_one();
    if (m_thread.joinable())
        m_thread.join();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "main - start" << std::endl;

    {
        Gateway gateway;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
        gateway.on_close(true);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20));
    }

    std::cout << "main - end" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Наверное, в данном примере мне стоит сделать мембер класса m_connected атомарной переменной (std::atomic_bool), поскольку метод is_connected() является публичным, что в теории может привести к одновременному обращению к m_connected из разных потоков.
Либо же добавить (уже отдельный от m_mutex) mutable std::mutex (или же std::recursive_mutex), для синхронизации обращения к переменной m_connected из разных потоков.
@user7860670, я правильно думаю?